# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages - textarea not binding correctly in Chrome or IE

Tags: asp.net, textarea, razor-pages

I had finally got SignalR to send messages to a textarea successfully on my razor page, but for some reason the only browser that works is Microsoft Edge (using W10) Neither IE or Chrome displays the messages.

I've tried almost everything I can think of but nothing is fixing the issue.

I also find that an alert bar does not work in IE, but works in Chrome & Edge. Bit disappointing to find the number of issues that appear to stem between different browser platforms...

When testing between Edge & Chrome, joining the SignalR group using Chrome I know does work because I see the join message in Edge, so it seems we're dealing with simply a binding issue using Chrome, but as said all the below functionality using Edge is working Ok for me, very strange...

Razor Page:

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <label asp-for="SystemMapping" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="SystemMapping" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.SystemMappingID" name="group-name" id="group-name">
            <option>Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        @*Spare column here!*@
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 1em">
    <div class="col">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Inbound Events</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="20" id="inboundTextArea" oninput="countCharInbound(this)"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 1em">
    <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="eraseTextInbound();">
            Clear Window
            <i class="fas fa-broom"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="mb-2  mb-md-0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="join-group">
            Connect
            <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="mb-2  mb-md-0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="leave-group">
            Disconnect
            <i class="fas fa-pause"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="mb-2  mb-md-0"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Razor Page js script:

```
 <script>
// Clear Window button Inbound.
function eraseTextInbound() {
    document.getElementById("inboundTextArea").value = "";
    document.getElementById("inboundTextArea").innerHTML = "";
}
// Clear Window button Inbound.
function eraseTextOutbound() {
    document.getElementById("outboundTextArea").value = "";
    document.getElementById("outboundTextArea").innerHTML = "";
}
// When textarea reached x no. chars, clear text.
function countCharInbound(val) {
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len >= 10000) {
        document.getElementById("inboundTextArea").value = "";
        document.getElementById("inboundTextArea").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
// When textarea reached x no. chars, clear text.34
function countCharOutbound(val) {
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len >= 10000) {
        document.getElementById("outboundTextArea").value = "";
        document.getElementById("outboundTextArea").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

```
  <script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
  <script src="~/js/systemEvents.js"></script>
```

SignalR js file script:

```
 "use strict";

 const connection = new 
 signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/messageHub").build();

 // Function binds the Inbound messages received from
 // SignalR to the inboundTextArea
 connection.on("Send", function (message) {
var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
var div = document.createElement("div");
// The <hr> tag defines a thematic break in an HTML page (e.g. a shift of topic).
//div.innerHTML = msg + "<hr/>"; // + "<hr/>" adds a line underneath each event message.
div.innerHTML = msg
document.getElementById("inboundTextArea").appendChild(div);
 });
```

Comment: Just update/clear the innerHTML of the textarea.  That's where the text should be... no need to create a div.  I don't see a "value" in your markup so not sure why you're trying to set that.  That might be causing an error.

Comment: Tried that, made no difference, still only works in Edge, but not chrome or IE

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution here: 
Changing the js script below has at least started showing the messages appear in Chrome as well as Edge, IE still not working though...

```
 // Function binds the Inbound messages received from SignalR to the inboundTextArea.
 connection.on("Send", (message) => {
 var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
 $("#inboundTextArea").val($("#inboundTextArea").val() + '\n' + msg);
 });
```